# Is a DVD drive needed when building a PC

Tags: drivers, dvd

I want to build myself a computer for the first time. And after watching some videos on how to assemble a computer I am a little bit confused.

With the Mainboard, GPU, ... often comes some sort of driver disc. Do I need to install the drivers? Because right now I have a case that does not provide space for a DVD drive and I don't really need it either way.

In some of the videos they have a DVD drive, whereas in other ones they don't have. But they never show the setup of a computer after putting the parts together.

So now the final question is: Do I need some sort of external DVD drive or can I wait with installing the drivers after connecting my computer to the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With the Mainboard, GPU, ... often comes some sort of driver disc.

True. But the drivers on those discs are often already outdated when you get the hardware. So you want to ignore those disks anyway.

> Do I need to install the drivers? Because right now I have a case that 
>   does not provide space for a DVD drive and I don't really need it either
>   way.

You often want or need to install some drivers. But that will work fine if installed via an USB pendrive, some folder on the hardisk, directly from the web, ...   No need to involve ancient ODD here.

Usually I download all the drivers (latest version) and put them on the same folder as the pendrive used to instal the OS.

So, no, you do not need them.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't need a DVD drive. USB 2.0 ports will work without extra drivers, just use a 2nd computer that does have a DVD drive and copy the content of the DVD to a USB stick then load the drivers from that.

Comment: While the above answers the question as asked, it is worth noting that, in order to install the OS to begin with, (a) the target computer needs to be able to boot off USB media, and (b) the 2nd computer will need software to create bootable USB media off a DVD or ISO image.

Comment: @dxiv Well, Windows is on a USB drive so no problems there